# In a arcgis,does clone a group copy feature layers as well??

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, arcgis

recently I was trying to clone a group and contents using python api in jupyter notebook. I could clone the group and contents but had a issue with copying the feature layers. the feature layer are copied with size of 1KB and we couldn't load it. Is there any way to copy the feature layer using Jupoyter Notebook?

Comment: What Python API are you using?

Comment: Its GIS api, python api for arcgis

Comment: You should write in your question that you are using the [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/) rather than ArcPy then.